# How Parallel Run Of Calling A Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, methods, parallels

Given the following code:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(link1))
{
    string[] link1_ar = link1.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string page1 = link1_ar[1];
    string filter1 = link1_ar[2];
    string code2 = link2_ar[3];
    MyMethod(summary, page1, filter1, code1);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(link2))
{
    string[] link2_ar = link2.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string page2 = link2_ar[1];
    string filter2 = link2_ar[2];
    string code2 = link2_ar[3];
    MyMethod(summary, page2, filter2, code2);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(link3))
{
    string[] link3_ar = link3.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string page3 = link3_ar[1];
    string filter3 = link3_ar[2];
    string code3 = link3_ar[3];
    MyMethod(summary, page3, filter3, code3);
}


    private void MyMethod(ref string summary, string bid_page, string bid_filter, string bid_code, string bid_silver)
    {
        bla bla bla
    }
```

i want to run three MyMethod together at a same time!
what should i change in these codes for getting that purpose?

Comment: It highly depends on what's inside MyMethod, and if it's thread safe.

Comment: Seeing as you've specified that this is ASP.NET, do you intend to block the current page response thread until all three `MyMethod` background calls complete?

Comment: Considering that `summary` is passed as `ref` to each of them, it's likely that `MyMethod` modifies `summary`, so it's not thread safe currently. Switch that to a `StringBuilder` with proper thread synchronization, and it'd probably be alright, but if the majority of the work in `MyMethod` is the string manipulation, then there's going to be very little work done outside of the synchronization, and therefore little benefit to doing this in parallel.

Comment: hi guys, MyMethod is a big one and i want paralellism because of speed. i don't want to block any thing.

Comment: i can replace that summary with a return string of that method.

Comment: @MoonLight - You don't need to write the code of MyMethod. Just describe what it does.

Comment: Given the information you have posted so far, there isn't any compelling reason to believe making this code multi-threaded will yield any speed increase whatsoever.

Comment: it has some Requests And Responces and i am so sad because of their speed in .net (against php), also i should keep some values during Requests and Responces in database / just this...

Comment: If your .NET code is slower than the equivalent in PHP then I suspect you're doing something wrong here.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your MyMethod is actually thread safe then the following should work using the Parallel.ForEach() method in .Net 4.0.  I'm tracking the individual summaries in a ConcurrentDictionary so you can reference them by link later if you need to.

I've also assumed that you changed MyMethod() to return the summary.

```
List<string> links = new List<string>() { link1, link2, link3};

ConcurrentDictionary<string, string> summariesByLink = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, string>();

Parallel.ForEach(links, link => {

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(link))
  {
    string[] link_ar = link.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string page = link_ar[1];
    string filter = link_ar[2];
    string code = link_ar[3];
    string summary = MyMethod( page, filter, code);

    summariesByLink.Add(link, summary);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks man for the answer, paralellism is my favorite. i will accept your answer. but is it possbile show us the other ways for learning.

Comment: What do you mean "the other ways"?  @Scott's answer shows using the Task framework.  What else are you curious about?

Answer (score 1):

Try wrappering each call to MyMethod in a task and then waiting for them all to complete.

```
var tasks = new List<Task>();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(link1))
{
    string[] link1_ar = link1.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string page1 = link1_ar[1];
    string filter1 = link1_ar[2];
    string code2 = link2_ar[3];
    var link1task = Task.Run(MyMethod(summary, page1, filter1, code1));
    tasks.Add(link1task);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(link2))
{
    string[] link2_ar = link2.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string page2 = link2_ar[1];
    string filter2 = link2_ar[2];
    string code2 = link2_ar[3];
    var link2task = Task.Run(MyMethod(summary, page2, filter2, code2));
    tasks.Add(link2task);
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(link3))
{
    string[] link3_ar = link3.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.None);
    string page3 = link3_ar[1];
    string filter3 = link3_ar[2];
    string code3 = link3_ar[3];
    var link3task = Task.Run(MyMethod(summary, page3, filter3, code3));
    tasks.Add(link3task);
}

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```